# Is there a difference when using curl and grep to a URL on a 32-bit machine?

Tags: python, curl, grep, ngrok

I need help with a problem that I cannot understand why it happens. I have a project that works through `ngrok` and generates a `tcp` link for each user, currently my project is causing problems for 32 bits users but not 64 bits. The generated tcp link is obtained as follows:

```
while True:
    tcp = os.popen('curl -s -N http://127.0.0.1:4040/status | grep -o "tcp://[0-9]*.tcp.ngrok.io:[0-9]*"').read()
    if re.match("tcp://[0-9]*.tcp.ngrok.io:[0-9]*", tcp) != None:
        print("\n{0}Ngrok TCP: {1}{2}".format(GREEN, DEFAULT, tcp))
        break
```

This code works fine, but not for 32 bits users, it remains as a loop without termination. To check what was happening, I installed a 32 bits virtual machine and realized this... Doing `curl -s -N http://localhost:4040 > result.txt` on a 64 bits machine i get [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/elliotmxr/418b93e556b99f455bcc3e16eb6bb015/raw/8644255f1ae92a26e17af025fa538970f208c1ca/gistfile1.txt), and on a `32 bits` machine i get [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/elliotmxr/a7158f522dd228442dbb733d30ff3a9f/raw/e90be1db879c9f35027c94e4057462f3af0b60f4/32-bits).

When you see the content of the files, you will notice that in the `64 bits` file, if we do a search for `"tcp://"` the link will appear, but if we do the same with the `32 bits` one, it does not appear, so when we do `grep` nothing appears.

My question is what can I do to fix this problem? Hope I explained it well, if possible try to replicate the same procedure to check, is there any other way to get the `tcp` link that `ngrok` generates while running in the background?

Comment: Could we perhaps see the *server* code? After all, that's where the different-depending-on-the-client data *comes from*. Maybe it cares about something about the client *other than* the architecture word size.

Comment: The server I run it like this simply: `os.system('./ngrok tcp -config=.config/ngrok.yml 443 > /dev/null 2>&1 &')`

Comment: The code works well in 64-bit architectures but 32-bit does not work because of the difference found in the 2 files that I linked above

Comment: My thought is that maybe "this machine is 64-bit and that machine is 32-bit" is *not* the reason why the server gives different data to those two machines. After all, *how would it know*? That's not, AFAICT, part of [the information the server would receive in the request header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that the code is running locally, separately on the two machines. Do they have the same version of ngrok installed? The same version of Python? The same contents in their respective `.config/ngrok.yml` files?

Comment: To answer your question, no, there is nothing in `curl` or `grep` which causes the difference you are seeing. You would get the same result if you fixed the code to fetch the content and parse it in Python entirely. (In fact you probably should; using two external processes for something Python can easily do natively is clumsy and inefficient.)

Comment: The tool is developed in python3.7 I have it in a private github repository and those with 32-bit architecture cannot use it due to the aforementioned problem, the ngrok file varies according to the system's own architecture, the script takes care of download the appropriate version of ngrok, and something that should be mentioned is that if I run ngrok manually without using the script, it works correctly and the ngrok web interface is also accessible, that's why it all seems very strange.
And if it is the same content in the `ngrok.yml` file

Comment: @tripleee, sorry I'm not a python expert and that's why I'm here

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html shows how to download a URL using the standard library. I assume you can figure out how to pull the link out of the result using regular string functions, or the `re` library if you really want to use a regular expression.

Comment: did you test it on 64bit and 32bit using other tools - like `wget` or even web browser? You can also use `curl` with `https://httpbin.org/get` to see if both versions send the same headers. Maybe server try to generate different content for different devices/browsers and then it may need correct header `User-Agent` to recognize device/browser.

Comment: @furas I tried the `curl` with the URL you provided and in the 2 it appears the same there were no differences, instead when doing it with the `ngrok` interface it keeps giving me the same problem

Comment: with `wget` the same error follows too, and on my 64-bit machine none of these errors appear

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem so I'll put it in case someone gets the same error, I was doing the procedure with the most current version of `ngrok`, so what I did was try an old version and try with the version `2.2.8` I was able to fix it. I downloaded it from here: https://dl.equinox.io/ngrok/ngrok/stable/archive